# best practice to manage GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, android-googleapiclient

I have a background service which runs in the background tracking device location using a `PendingIntent`.

The service calls `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, locationRequest, pendingIntent`) to start location tracking but also sometimes to update the location tracking (change the frequency of updates).

Should I store the `GoogleApiClient` instance in the service class or should I connect to it each time I need it?

- I'm worried if I store it, disconnection can appear. This shouldn't be a problem in theory because the documentation says `GoogleApiClient` automatically tries to reconnect itself.
- If I connect each time to `GoogleApiClient`, it adds a bit of complexity in the code, because the connection made with `connect()` is asynchronous.

Based on your experience, what do you think is best?

Answer (score 0):

You should call `googleApiClient.connect()` in `onStart()` of your activity and `googleApiClient.disconnect()` in `onStop()`. You can implement `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`, which will let you know if the client connects successfully via invoking `public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)` and then you can access your api.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the description. I have a background service. I am worried about disconnection.